# Can't Get TinyCom GUI to Execute

Tags: python, user-interface

I installed TinyCom with "pip install tinycom" and the install was successful. The documentation says to "simply execute TinyCom", which I interpret as to click the execute file. I've made sure PyQT5 and PySide installed, yet nothing happens when I click the execute file. I'm not sure if I'm missing a step, or not understanding the documentation.

I've made sure python, PyQT5, and Pyside are installed. I've trying to run the execute file from within PyCharm. I've tried to run the executable as an admin.